# pandas: How to count the unique categories?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "col_cate": ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
            "target_bool": [True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]
        }
    )
```

And I want to count the number of unique categories. So I am expecting the output to be like this

```
col_cate, target_bool, cnt
'A'     , True       , 2
'A'     , False      , 2
'B'     , True       , 2
'B'     , False      , 2
```

But `df_input.group_by(["col_cate", "target_bool"]).count()` gives

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(A, False), (A, True), (B, False), (B, True)]
```

But adding a `dummy` to the `df_input` works, like `df_input["dummy"] = 1`.

How do I get the group by count table without adding a dummy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because function [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) is used for counts values with exclude missing values if exist is necessary specify column after groupby, if both columns are used in `by` parameter in `groupby`:

```
df = (df_input.groupby(by=["col_cate", "target_bool"])['col_cate']
              .count()
              .reset_index(name='cnt'))
print (df)
  col_cate  target_bool  cnt
0        A        False    2
1        A         True    2
2        B        False    2
3        B         True    2
```

If want count all columns, here both is it possible (but here always same output) if specify both columns:

```
df1 = (df_input.groupby(["col_cate", "target_bool"])[['col_cate','target_bool']]
               .count()
               .add_suffix('_count')
               .reset_index())
print (df1)
  col_cate  target_bool  col_cate_count  target_bool_count
0        A        False               2                  2
1        A         True               2                  2
2        B        False               2                  2
3        B         True               2                  2
```

Or if use  [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) method it working a bit different - it count all values, not exclude missing, so no column is necessary specify:

```
df = df_input.groupby(["col_cate", "target_bool"]).size().reset_index(name='cnt')
print (df)
  col_cate  target_bool  cnt
0        A        False    2
1        A         True    2
2        B        False    2
3        B         True    2
```

Answer (score 7):

```
df_input.groupby('col_cate')['target_bool'].value_counts()

col_cate  target_bool
A         False          2
          True           2
B         False          2
          True           2
```

then you can reset_index()

Comment: this is more pythonic

Comment: @XaviorL - hmmm, difference is default sorting in `value_counts` per groups, so it is different like `size` or `count` methods (there is no default soring).

Answer (score 1):

Like this also:

```
In [54]: df_input.groupby(df_input.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().\ 
    ...:     rename(columns={0:'cnt'}) 
Out[54]: 
  col_cate  target_bool  cnt
0        A        False    2
1        A         True    2
2        B        False    2
3        B         True    2
```